# Menu and links are overlapping to the left

Tags: css, navigation, alignment

I am having trouble with a website I am developing. In Chrome (and only some of the time in Chrome) I get this problem where my nav menu overlaps to the left.

Also links are getting shoved around in the wrong place (sometimes appearing under or over the text around them. There is an obvious problem with the phone number at the top of the page as well (which isn't a link).

See the attached screen shot. The website is [mexican-getaway.com](http://mexican-getaway.com/)

Any idea on where my code is going crazy?

[image: Website Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me as well - no words are getting cut off. (Using Chrome on Mac OS 10.8.2)